# How to inject text globally into memoir class crosshead chapterstyle

Tags: memoir, chapters

I wish to add a pifont character (actually `\ding{80}`) to appear spaced after all chapter numbers, and spaced before chapter headings, like this: `2 * Light`, where `*` represents the character I want injected into the chapterstyle.

[memoir.dtx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) shows that this crosshead chapterstyle includes:

```
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
```

And LarsMadsen's [MemoirChapStyles.pdf](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/documentation/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf) > `Source for the AlexanderGrebenkov style` contains this line in that style's definition:

```
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{. }
```

So I assumed I could do the same trick with the crosshead chapterstyle. This is what I tried as a first shot (injecting just a `*`, not a pifont yet):

```
\documentclass[mypreferences]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{crosshead}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{ * }
```

- but that last line creates nothing new.

So how do I make this work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non problem, apparently solved by cleaning up the code and removing the auxiliary files

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "but that last line creates nothing new"?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{crosshead}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{ * }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) points out, my code does actually work, which I discovered after deleting all of the latex-produced files and running TeXstudio on my `tex` file afresh. So, having specified:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
```

I'm able to:

```
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\normalsize\ding{80}\quad}
```

which works (but, I can now see clearly, is too distracting and not what I want):

[image: ding80 in crosshead]

Comment: I've used a centered dot for some projects. I think it is called `\textcentereddot` or similar, it is in the symbols list. BTW: you should not answer your own question, update it instead.